# JSON specific entities to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON dataset coming from server side like :

```
[
{"id":1, "year":"2001", "magnitude":20},
{"id":2, "year":"2020", "magnitude":21},
{"id":3, "year":"2040", "magnitude":22}
]
```

I want to convert these data-sets as JavaScript arrays. For example, for year and magnitude in the json. I want these data in Javascript as:

```
var year = [2001, 2020, 2040];
var magnitude = [20, 21, 22];
```

I have tried different solutions but getting undefined while I alert to test data. How should I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your code which got undefined, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of the wanted keys and collect the values in an object. Later destructure the object and get the wanted arrays.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, year: "2001", magnitude: 20 }, { id: 2, year: "2020", magnitude: 21 }, { id: 3, year: "2040", magnitude: 22 }],
    keys = ['year', 'magnitude'],
    collection = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach(k => r[k].push(o[k]));
        return r;
    }, Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: [] })))),
    { year, magnitude } = collection;

console.log(year);
console.log(magnitude);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Loop through the entries of each object and update the accumulator. This works for *any* number of properties in the inner objects:

```js
const input=[{id:1,year:"2001",magnitude:20},{id:2,year:"2020",magnitude:21},{id:3,year:"2040",magnitude:22}];

let merged = input.reduce((r, a) => {
  Object.entries(a).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    r[k] = r[k] || [];
    r[k].push(v)
  })

  return r;
}, {})

let { id, year, magnitude } = merged;

console.log(id)
console.log(year)
console.log(magnitude)
```

This is what `merged` looks like:

```
{
   "id": [1, 2, 3],
   "year": ["2001", "2020", "2040"],
   "magnitude": [20, 21, 22]
}
```

Comment: Clever destructuring here. Definitely an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a function and use `map` to get a dynamic property.

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, year: "2001", magnitude: 20 }, { id: 2, year: "2020", magnitude: 21 }, { id: 3, year: "2040", magnitude: 22 }]

const getBy = key => data.map(e => e[key])

console.log(getBy('year'))
console.log(getBy('magnitude'))
console.log(getBy('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the map() method for arrays would be the most modern solution for this task. Basically what it does is return a new array based on the function you provide:

```
var json = [
    {"id":1, "year":"2001", "magnitude":20},
    {"id":2, "year":"2020", "magnitude":21},
    {"id":3, "year":"2040", "magnitude":22}
];
var year = json.map(arr => arr.year);
var magnitude = json.map(arr => arr.magnitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name of the object you get from server is 'response'.

```
var years = response.map(el => el.year);
var magnitudes = response.map(el => el.magnitude);
```

Here's a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gadawag/uye8kmvf/

Answer (score -1):

First parse the JSON and then use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function

```js
const data = '[{"id":1, "year":"2001", "magnitude":20},{"id":2, "year":"2020", "magnitude":21},{"id":3, "year":"2040", "magnitude":22}]';

const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
const years = parsed.map(item => item.year);
const magnitudes = parsed.map(item => item.magnitude);

console.log('years', years);
console.log('magnitudes', magnitudes);
```

1) I noted a JSON issue in your example. There was a comma missing after the second item.
2) If you want to parse the years to numbers you can do this:

```
const years = parsed.map(item => Number.parseInt(item.year, 10));
```